# Getting lines to work on Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

So I've been sifting through GE's documentation, and found how to do LineStyle and LineString to style and display a line, but in practice I cannot actually make it work. Here's my KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Style id="thisStyle">
<LineStyle>
<color>500078F0</color>
<colorMode>Normal</colorMode>
<width>5</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>502-2012-11-19 05:27:03</name>
<description>Speed:0</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-76.0513,42.0894,247</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>502-2012-11-19 05:26:46</name>
<description>Speed:0</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-76.0517,42.0886,287</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
....
<Placemark>
<name>525-2012-11-19 04:38:25</name>
<description>Speed:0</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-76.0512,42.0894,178</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<styleUrl>#thisStyle</styleUrl>
<LineString>
<tessellate>1</tessellate>
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
<coordinates>
-76.0513,42.0894,247 
-76.0517,42.0886,287 
....
-76.0512,42.0894,178 
</coordinates></LineString></Document></kml>
```

Note: The above places where "..." appears there are about 50 more coordinate sets, I removed them for the sake of brevity, but since all coordinates are produced by a script if one works I know they all will. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction as to why my placemarks all show up, but no lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [LineString](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) element is only valid inside a Placemark (or a MultiGeometry inside a Placemark):

```
<Placemark>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>
      -76.0513,42.0894,247 
      -76.0517,42.0886,287 
      -76.0512,42.0894,178 
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

- [Example on Google Maps with your KML](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_noLines_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=40.07304,-74.724323&sspn=4.287493,10.821533&t=h&z=19)
- [Example on Google Maps with a Placemark containing the Linestring](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_noLinesA_kml.xml&hl=en&ll=42.088999,-76.051451&spn=0.001027,0.002642&sll=42.088993,-76.051451&sspn=0.001027,0.002642&t=h&z=19)

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains what the issue is. After putting the Placemark tag around my LineString it is working perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You must either inline Style in the Placemark or reference the style in the Placemark using *styleUrl* element.

The last Placemark in your example needs to be rewritten like this:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>525-2012-11-19 04:38:25</name>
    <description>Speed:0</description>
    <styleUrl>#thisStyle</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>
            -76.0513,42.0894,247 
            -76.0517,42.0886,287
             ...
            -76.0512,42.0894,178 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

If your KML doesn't view correctly then it usually helps to validate the KML. You can use the [KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the tip with the KML Validator. Both answers were correct, but I try to always mark the first correct one to be fair. Thank you so much for your help and code, I truly appreciate it.